# Size of a directory in Windows

Tags: windows, directory, size

Is there a command to get the size of a directory in Windows? The result should only give the size and nothing else. The command dir gives a lot of information.

Comment: What's the size of a directory? The size of the on-disk structure? The size of all the files contained in that directory? Or including subdirectories? What about symbolic links? The logical size of files, or the on-disk size? What about sparse files or compressed files? And how is this a programming problem anyway?

Comment: The size of all the files contained in that directory, including subdirectories.

Comment: That leaves *many* questions unanswered: How do you want to deal with symbolic links? Which size do you want reported (size of file, size on disk, something else)? And how is this a programming problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a value=0
set /a sum=0
FOR /R %1 %%I IN (*) DO (
set /a value=%%~zI/1024
set /a sum=!sum!+!value!
)
@echo !sum!